# Average percentage of soccer games being tied

Tags: probability

Assume a fair soccer match lasting 10 minutes with on average one goal scored per minute.

**Percentage wise, how often is the game tied (score is 0:0,1:1,...,n:n)?**

Can I simply assume a match is tied 33% of the total time (and 66% of the time either one team is leading) or do I miss something less obvious?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid not.  Buckle in, this is going to be a bumpy ride.

First, you have to compute the probability of 2k goals being scored per match.  (We're only interested in even goals since those are whre the score is tied)  This is a Poisson distribution with a mean of 10, so that probability is $$\frac{10^{2k}e^{-10}}{(2k)!}$$
Then you need to calculate the probability that they were evenly split between the two teams.  Assuming the teams are equally likely to score, this probability is $$\frac{\binom{2k}{k}}{2^{2k}}$$

So the final answer is $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\binom{2k}{k}10^{2k}e^{-10}}{(2k)!2^{2k}}\approx12.8\ \%$$

Comment: Your answer gives:  $0.127833.$

Comment: does that also apply for the time in the game. E.g if the game lasts 10 Minutes, can I expect the game to be on a tied score for 1:17 minutes in that game or is what you mentioned rather the probability of the match ending tied?

Comment: Yes, we made the assumption that the expected number of goals per game would be 10 -- one per minute for ten minutes.  You could replace those 10's with different numbers if you wanted to model lower-scoring games

Comment: An alternative approach (each team independently scores an average of $5$ goals, Poisson distributed) would give the same answer $\displaystyle\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty\left(\frac{5^{k}e^{-5}}{k!}\right)^2 \approx 0.127833$

Comment: True, and much prettier!